# Sencha Touch 1.1, PhoneGap 1.2, Android Text Area/Text Field scrolling issue

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I have spent a lot of time researching this issue and even more time trying to solve it. I am hoping someone out there knows a good solution for this. The issue involves Sencha Touch 1.1, PhoneGap 1.2 and Android. I am months into the project and have encountered an issue with panels sliding up when a text area or text field receives focus and when soft keyboard input is received while the input has focus.

I have read several other stack overflow and sencha forum threads that describe variations of the same problem. The usual solution provided is to set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan instead of adjustResize. This does get rid of the problem of having the panel slide up but is not acceptable in my case because one of the panels in the application is a chat window. The input field must always stay docked against the bottom visible area on the screen. For example, it should stay docked to the bottom of the screen when no soft keyboard is visible and it should stay docked just above the soft keyboard when the keyboard is out. I am able to accomplish this if I resize the panel to the viewport height when Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize is called (using android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize). The problem is that any keyboard input causes the entire panel to slide up. A very hacky and ultimately unacceptable solution has been to listen for key events and then manually slide the panel back to 0,0 by setting it's position and also calling window.scrollTo(0,0). This does cause the panel to get back into place but is a poor user experience (having the screen bounce up and down with each letter input).

Using android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan does not cause any panel shifting but does not provide any means of obtaining the soft keyboard's height so that I can properly position the chat's input field directly above the soft keyboard (none that I am aware of anyway).

Question 1: Is there a way to programmatically determine the height of a soft keyboard without using android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize and listening to the Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize event to read the size of the resized viewport?

Question 2: Is there a way to use android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize and prevent the browser from sliding up when a text field or text area receives focus?

Thanks in advance for any help. This has consumed 30+ hours of time and is pretty much a show stopper for this app that is now several months into development.

-Sean

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem? I'm facing it too.. :(

Comment: I have not found a solution for the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I've been suffering this very same problem with Sencha Touch 1.1 and PhoneGap 1.2; I have a card layout with toolbars docked to the top and bottom, the bottom toolbar contains a text field that should stay docked to the bottom of the viewport and not be covered up by the soft keyboard, à la iOS Messages app.

I think (he says tentatively) that setting `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` and adding an `onWindowResize` event handler which manually does the component resizing should fix things:

```
if (Ext.is.Android) {
  Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function() {
    Ext.Viewport.scrollToTop();
    Ext.Viewport.updateBodySize();
    Ext.Viewport.fireEvent('resize', Ext.Viewport, Ext.getBody().getSize());
    myapp.views.viewport.getActiveItem().fireEvent('resize');
  });
}
```

The `…getActiveItem().fireEvent('resize')` just calls a `resize` listener in the current card in which there's some manual repainting of the bottom toolbar.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT: "Ext.EventManager" -- This object has been deprecated in Sencha Touch 2.0.0. Please refer to the method documentation for specific alternatives.**

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.util.TextArea', {
override: 'Ext.form.TextArea',
adjustHeight: Ext.Function.createBuffered(function (textarea) {
    var textAreaEl = textarea.getComponent().input;
    if (textAreaEl) {
        textAreaEl.dom.style.height = 'auto';
        textAreaEl.dom.style.height = textAreaEl.dom.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}, 200, this),

constructor: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.on({
        scope: this,
        keyup: function (textarea) {
            textarea.adjustHeight(textarea);
        },
        change: function (textarea, newValue) {
            textarea.adjustHeight(textarea);
        }
    });
}});
```